# Ubuntu 22.10 no display on second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, 22.10

My current set up is as follows;

```
Ubuntu 22.10 (same issue existed for 22.04)
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 graphics card
Using NVIDIA proprietary drivers (515)
Samsung G9 49" Curved Monitor (DP/HDMI)
Acer 22" Monitor (HDMI)
```

I have scoured the internet and can not for the life of me get the second monitor to work.
I've tried a singular set up and both screens are working, but the moment I plug a second one in, the first one continues to work but "no input detected" on the second one.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas are welcome.